# How to use my shared host directory with aws route 53 subdomain?

Tags: shared-hosting, amazon-aws, route53

I have my web application hosted on shared hosting provider(A2hosting). i need to link my web files on my shared hosting sever to a sub domain on aws route 53. can someone advice me for this?

Comment: It appears that A2hosting uses Plesk to let you manage your sites.  Is this going to be your first site (main domain) or an additional domain (add-on domain)?

Comment: i want to use it as a add-on domain. i have this shared hosting account and a aws ec2 instance. my domain is in godaddy, configured with aws DNS records. now i need to create another sub domain which needs to connect with the site in my shared host. simply i need to use both aws and shared host with my domain.